# CSS input[date] : How to remove gadgets

Tags: css, date, input

I need to use a clean `input[date]` CSS. For this, I'm wondering how to remove or disable the following items:

1. How to remove the **blue border** ?
2. How to **prevent editing** the day, month and year individually ? (and thus, don't have the blue background box)
3. How to remove the **cross** ?
4. How to remove the **double arrow** ?
5. Although I just want to keep the **triangle gadget** to choose the date at the end of the `input[date]`, I'd like to know how to remove it.

[image]

**=== SOLUTIONS ===**

3. The cross can be removed by using the `required="required"` argument in the `input` tag. But the space it occupy is still here.

Comment: Why you don't use calender plugin of javascript?

Comment: I didn't know about it, I'll check it. But the `input[date]` would be fine to me if I can adjust the CSS.

Comment: By the way, `blue border` means highlight?

Comment: Here is something you could look at to get rid of the spinner: https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/turn-off-number-input-spinners/ Try it on the date.

Comment: I think you should use javascript calender plugin. Otherwise modify this css http://jsfiddle.net/e75brw3u/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use CSS to hide elements but in order to prevent individual editing, you have to write some scripts. And putting a `onkeydown="return false"` will do the trick

```css
/* To remove default blue outline */
input[type='date']:focus {
  outline: none;
}

/*  To remove cross sign */
input[type="date"]::-webkit-clear-button {
    display: none;
}

input[type="date"]::-ms-clear {
    display: none;
}

/* To remove Spin Arrows */
input[type="date"]::-webkit-inner-spin-button {
    display: none;
}

/* To remove Drop down Arrow */
input[type="date"]::-webkit-calendar-picker-indicator {
  display: none;  
}
```

```html
<input type="date" onkeydown="return false"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

I found some solutions for your trouble. But I didn't find all.

```css
input::-webkit-outer-spin-button,
input::-webkit-inner-spin-button {
    -webkit-appearance: none;
    margin: 0; /* <-- Apparently some margin are still there even though it's hidden */
}

input::-webkit-clear-button {
    display: none;
}

.custom {
  outline: none;
}
```

```html
<input type="date" class="custom" onkeydown="return false"/>
```

I removed **blue border**, **cross**, **double arrow**, and **prevented editing individually**.